# Disabling validation on all forms when user closes application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation

Is there an easy way to disable all form validation when the user clicks on the "X" icon to close an application or when the user clicks on a button in the application that closes the application?

I found this but it's in C#. Can you convert this into VB.Net coding?

http://geekswithblogs.net/dapostolov/archive/2009/06/14/the-validating-event-can-prevent-a-form-closing-properly.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Found it!

I put this code in the button click handlers:

```
' Disable validation on the form.
'--------------------------------
Me.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable
```

When I call the forms again I use this for a form object called objFormParents:

```
' Reset validation on this form because the user may have closed it before.
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
objFormParents.CausesValidation = True
```

I found this on the internet to handle clicking on the "X" icon:

```
' This will allow the user to close the form without the worry of controls doing validation from "X".
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

    Select Case ((m.WParam.ToInt64() And &HFFFF) And &HFFF0)

        Case &HF060 ' The user chose to close the form.
            Me.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable
    End Select

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to implement this solution

First you declare a public property

```
Private bFormClosing As Boolean = False
```

then you include this Boolean in your validation code with an AND like

```
. . . And bFormClosing = False then
```

here you use

```
    ErrorProvider.SetError("My Error Message")
    e.Cancel = True
Else 
    e.Cancel = False
```

you do this trick for all of the validating control events, then in the Enter Event of the `Exit_Button` that triggers before the validating event, you set the `bClosingForm = true`

Then it triggers a cascading event and go to the validating event to perform the `AND bFormClosing`, and will jump to the `else` were you have the `e.Cancel = false` AND will disable the validation and allow you to close the form of all the controls validating events.

Remember to set to false the `CausesValidation` = false of the exit button.

Also you can put it in the mouse down even or ClosingForm Event, any event that triggers before the validating event. Hurray it work for me, finally!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much simpler.

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.WParam.ToInt32 = &HF060 Then Me.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```